# Modelica Standard Library 3.2.2

Tags: modelica, standard-library, openmodelica

Where can I download the older versions of Modelica Standard Library like 3.2.2? Then, is it possible to call it from OpenModelica?

Comment: https://github.com/modelica/ModelicaStandardLibrary/releases

Comment: Try to unload the current version of MSL in OM, then load the older version.

Comment: I found a simple solution that I'd like to share here; in OM toolbar, click on Tools -> Options -> on the list on left hand side choose libraries -> on right side double click on Modelica -> there you go, you can change the version of MSL without downloading or uploading any other libraries.

Comment: Any idea if Dymola supports the same thing?

Comment: In Dymola, it can be under tools ->library management; however, I have not tried it.